# field emptied while submited but object filled on the controller side

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I first display my page, the field are valued correctly. But when I submit the form in the method `addCouloir` below, the field is displayed empty. Yet the topologie instance is still well valued at the last line of the addCouloir method (I've inspected the object in debug mode).

Other fields of the same instance of the topologie object are well displayed on the same. So it could be related to the `select/disabled` kind of field

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "topologie", types = { Topologie.class })
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologieInstanceCouloir")
public class TopologieInstanceCouloirController {

...
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "addCouloir" })
    public String addCouloir(final Topologie topologie, final Model model,
            final HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        final String param = req.getParameter("addCouloir");
        logger.info("REST request to add Couloir : {}", param);

        final Matcher matcher = patternPartitionInstance.matcher(param);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            final Integer partitionId = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
            final Integer instanceId = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
            logger.info("Add a new Couloir on Instance {} on partition  {}",
                    instanceId, partitionId);
            topologie.getPartitions().get(partitionId.intValue())
            .getInstances().get(instanceId).getCouloirs()
            .add(new Couloir());
        }

        return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE_INSTANCECOULOIR;
    }
```

The html/thymeleaf topologieInstanceCouloir.html corresponding code :

```
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/bus/topologieInstanceCouloir}"
            th:object="${topologie}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
...
            <div class="form-group"
                th:if="${#bools.isFalse(topologie.isPassageCvs)}">
                <label th:for="*{environnement}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Environnement</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select th:field="*{environnement}" class="form-control"
                        th:disabled="disabled">
                        <option th:each="environnement : ${allEnvironnement}"
                            th:value="${environnement}" th:text="${environnement}">...</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The button :

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
        name="addCouloir"
        th:value="'partitions[' + ${rowPartitionStat.index} + '].instances[' + ${rowInstanceStat.index} + ']'">Ajouter
        couloir</button>
</div>
```

The Topologie object related :

```
public class Topologie {
    private String environnement;
...
    public String getEnvironnement() {
        return environnement;
    }

    public void setEnvironnement(String environnement) {
        this.environnement = environnement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `@ModelAttribute("topologie")` on your `addCouloir` method.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for the proposal but it doesn't change anything. As said in the question, on the java side at the end of the addCouloir method the object is fine : the `environnement` field is filled with the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Elements that have been "disabled" do not submit their data.  Since topologie is on the session (`@SessionAttributes(value = "topologie", types = { Topologie.class })`), this means that it will keep it's original value regardless of what the value of the select is.

(I'm not completely sure what you mean by "well valued")

Comment: By well valued I mean that it keeps its original value. That's what I want it's just a way to recall the user this value without permitting change. Even when I remove the `disabled` attribute the environnement value is empty. Which is the behaviour I don't understand : I don't know where the value is changed.